# Chromium: How to build chromedriver.exe from source in Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, selenium-chromedriver, desktop-application, chromium, msysgit

I am following page for building chromedriver.exe from source code:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Get-the-code

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 as stated.
Also downloaded and extracted `depot_tools` in `C:\src\depot_tools`.

I have installed Python 2 and msysgit previously.
I have added depot_tools in `PATH` System Variables.

[image: Environment Variabes]

I have also added 'DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN' variable in System Variables with value `0`.

[image]

Now as stated I am running `gclient` command from cmd but nothing is working.

[image: gclient command not working in cmd]

I can't move further.
Also if you have any Video Referral please share as I didn't get any on Google search.

And if you know it well and would like to help please share your email id or twitter handle because it seems hard to get answers to such queries as there are only few such questions on StackOverflow and that too uanswered. So a contact might be helpful.

Comment: You destroyed the normal PATH, that is why it can't find Powershell anymore.  This can, ahem, cause a big headache with any other stuff you have installed.  You need to add back at least C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem and C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\  Next time change the User variables instead of the System variables, less risky.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't removed any stuff like you mentioned. But will add it. Is there anything else I should add?